# O significado de "pode deixar!"

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, uso-de-palavras

Qual é significado de ***pode deixar***?

Pelo o que eu percebi nas conversas, as pessoas usam isso para dizer, por exemplo, **’Fique tranquilo!’** É isso ou tem outro significado?

Comment: Podem também ser: paremos de falar sobre um assunto.

Comment: Pode Deixar = paremos de falar sobre um assunto????

Comment: Claro. Estou falando com você. Você fica cada vez mais irritado comigo. Você termina falando para mim: Pode deixar? Ou seja em bom português: Deixemos o assunto, por favor. Morou ou não morou? Outra gíria que lhe dou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É bem isso mesmo. Se poderia dizer que é **pode deixar (de lado)**, ou seja:

- não precisa fazer/falar mais nada
- não se preocupe
- fique tranquilo.

Ou seja, *don't worry*. Considerando isto, é próximo a [*rest assured*](https://www.wordreference.com/enpt/rest%20assured), mas esse é melhor traduzido como "pode confiar" ou "pode ter certeza". Oralmente a expressão é frequentemente reduzida para [**podexá**](https://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/podex%C3%A1/).

Em construções do tipo **pode deixar comigo** ou **pode deixar por minha conta** (ou ainda [**xá comigo**](https://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/x%C3%A1%20comigo/)), significa que eu vou me encarregar/tomar conta (*you can leave it to me*).

Numa resposta a um pedido, e.g., "Podes avisá-la? -- Pode deixar.", é uma afirmativa enfática, como "com certeza" ou "claro (que sim)" ([similar](https://www.wordreference.com/enpt/can%20do) a [*can do*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/can+do)).